# Domain redirected to frontend/web

Tags: yii2

When I access `http://alpha.myweb.com/` it redirected to `http://alpha.myweb.com/frontend/web/`

It resulting website show without any asset.

Here is my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName alpha.myweb.com
        ServerAlias www.alpha.myweb.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb
        #Options +FollowSymlinks

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my `.htaccess`

```
# prevent directory listings Options -Indexes IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links Options FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^administrator(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT] RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alpha\.myweb\.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://alpha.myweb.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What's wrong with my configuration? do I need to store `frontend/config/main.php`, `backend/config/main.php` and `common\config\main.php`

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache document root should be `/var/www/html/myweb/frontend/web` and not `/var/www/html/myweb` which is your project root.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Or restart apache after this changes